# xcode apply style of a button to another

Tags: ios, xcode

For some reason I cannot copy and paste one button to create another one, because when I alt+drag or copy and paste the old button, the new one is red and after build and run it doesn't show in screen.

Can someone tell me how to apply old style of a button to a new one?

Comment: What do you mean by red? Sounds like it's the constraints that are missing which would also explain why it isn't on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply cmd+c to copy and then cmd+v to paste, the red that you can see is a border to alert you that there is a problem with constraints(!) because you lose the constraints with the copy, this is why you can see the button, it is over the screen.

You can simply add the right constraints and the red border disappears and you can see your button in the mainView.

Comment: thx for the reply Kerberos, however I still cannot get the red to go away, I did find that after copy and paste the constraints changes from 5 of them to only 1, how can I restore those constraints

Comment: Yes the constraints to the superView disappear after the copy. You must add the new constraint again, as you did in the source button.

Comment: @TomDawn The red border disappear if you haven't anymore errors in the constraints. You can try help tapping the red arrow near the view.